# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager can generate two factor token, but SignInManager cannot evaluate a success authentication via Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I have an ASP.NET Web API which provides a login with two factor authentication. The process looks like this: Calls Login Function, which evaluates the username and password, and then returns back with an alert about an email with token code sent to the username's email. If I test token with copying into text field via Swagger in the same port with .net server, the process goes very well, but if I test it via angular which is working on different port, the SignInResult.Succeeded is Failed.
The server port: 44334
The client port: 4200
Is it something middleware configuration problem in .NET Web API?
There you go, 2 actions, thats evaluates the login parameters, and sends the token code to email address, and the Two-Factor token evaluation:

```
// POST: api/Account/login

[HttpPost]

[Route("login")]

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]

public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginDto loginDto)

{

string message = $"Login Attempt for {loginDto.Username} ";

_logger.LogInformation(message);

if (!ModelState.IsValid)

{

return BadRequest(ModelState);

}

try

{

ApiUser user = await _authenticationManagerService.ValidateUser(loginDto);

if (user != null) {

if (user.TwoFactorEnabled)

{

var token = await _userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider);

await _emailManagerService.SendEmailAsync(user.Email!, string.Format("{0} {1}", user.LastName, user.FirstName), token);

return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK,

new TokenRequest { Is2FA = true });

}

}

else

{

return BadRequest();

}

var tokenRequest = new TokenRequest { Token = await _authenticationManagerService.CreateToken(), RefreshToken = await _authenticationManagerService.CreateRefreshToken(), User = user };

return Accepted(tokenRequest);

}

catch (UnauthorizedException)

{

return Unauthorized();

}

catch (Exception)

{

throw;

}

}

[HttpPost]

[Route("verifytwofactor")]

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]

[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)]

public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyTwoFactor([FromBody] TwoFactorDto twoFactorDto)

{

var signIn = await _signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider, twoFactorDto.Code.ToString(), twoFactorDto.IsPersistent, false); // the error is here, when I attempt to evaluate via Angular

if (signIn.Succeeded) // It's returning false

{

var user = await _authenticationManagerService.ValidateUserAfter2FA(twoFactorDto.Username);

return Accepted(new TokenRequest { Token = await _authenticationManagerService.CreateToken(), RefreshToken = await _authenticationManagerService.CreateRefreshToken(), User = user });

}

else

{

return BadRequest();

}

}
```

And my middleware:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>

{

o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

})

.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, o =>

{

o.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;

o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

});
```

So the question is: How to fix this part to works properly the Token authentication via Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The error was the extension of IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme cookie, because it contains less information for the browser. So I extended it with more parameters, and the important: set the `options.Cookie.HttpOnly=false` to work properly via SPA with different port. So the solution:

```
.AddCookie(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme, options =>

{

options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";

options.Cookie.Name = IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme;

options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;

options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);

options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;

options.LoginPath = new PathString("/two-factor");

options.SlidingExpiration = true;

});
```